# Cura Slicing software failing to slice properly

Tags: creality-ender-3, ultimaker-cura

Sometimes Cura will slice a model and have failed lines of code. After discovering this problem I have tried re-slicing and then the code will come out fine. The first picture below is the failure point in the code from the first time I ran Cura's slicing. The second picture is the exact same model that I ran a second time through Cura and it came out fine. Is there any settings/reasons as to why this is happening?

Note, that I am also using an Ender 3 v2. For the time being I suppose I will have to look at the full code ahead of time to spot failure points.

[image: First Slicing of Model, which failed]

[image: 2nd Slicing of Model, which was successful]

Comment: Which version of Cura are you using? Is it the most recent? Have you tried slicing the same stl file with another slicer? What else have you tried?

Comment: Do you write directly to SD card? That looks like a writing error!

Answer (score 2):

The random appearance of the commands makes this appear as a writing error. I have had these happen in three cases:

- When I sliced an object and then saved to the SD card but removed the card before saving finished, the resulting file was corrupt and at times wouldn't even print.

  - Solution: Wait for Cura to tell that saving finished, then use eject before removing the card.
- When I sliced and saved, waited for completion, and yanked the card too quickly after that without using eject.

  - Solution: use the eject card button.
- When I used an adapter with a bad fit or connection to the SD card.

  - Solution: reseat the SD card or use a different adapter.